# Let $f(z) = \textrm{Log}(\textrm{Log} (z + 2i))$. Where is $f$ continuous?

Tags: complex-analysis, functions, continuity, logarithms

Let $f(z) = \textrm{Log}(\textrm{Log} (z + 2i))$. Where is $f$ continuous?

I have been having issues on determining the continuity of this double logarithmic complex function.

Do I approach this testing limits or derivatives of the function?

If anyone could help me here that would be great. Thanks

Comment: Usually the complex logarithm is defined as an analytic function on the whole complex plane except for a branch cut on the negative real axis (zero included), where it is discontinuous. Can you take it from here?

Comment: From this I take it that it is discontinuous along the negative real axis, $0$ included. Am I interpreting this correctly? Or is there more to this?

Comment: Correct. $\ln(x)$ is discontinuous on the negative real axis.

Comment: @lcv so is that answer sufficient to my example above? It seems very simplistic if so. Thanks for your help

Comment: No that's not sufficient. The question is for log(log()). You have to do a little work.

Comment: Sorry about the continued questions. Could the continuity of this function be checked using the polar co-ordinate Cauchy-Riemann equations?? I’m really not sure how to do the double log part.

Comment: Don't make your life complicated. It's just a composition of two functions. Write f=log(g) with g=log(w) (and eventually w=z+2i). Where is f discontinuous as a function of g? And so on..

Answer (score 0):

Let $w=\textrm{Log}(z+2i), \quad f(z) = \textrm{Log}(w(z))$.

We want (I.)  $z+2i \notin \{-\infty,0]$ and (II.) $w \notin \{-\infty,0]$.

I.  $$z \ne\alpha-2i, \quad \alpha \in (-\infty,0]$$

II.  $$\begin{aligned}  \textrm{Log}(z+2i) &\notin (-\infty,0] \\ z+2i &\ne e^\alpha, \quad \alpha \in (-\infty,0]\\ z &\ne \beta -2i, \quad \beta \in [0,1] \end{aligned} $$

In summary, for $f(z)$ to be defined, we want $z \notin \textrm{I} \cup \textrm{II}$:

$$z\ne \alpha -2i, \quad \alpha \in (-\infty, 1]$$

Since the logarithm is holomorphic where it is defined, this is also the condition for $f(z)$ to be continuous.

Comment: See also here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3568264/fz-textrmlog-textrmlog-z-2i-where-is-f-defined